# NiFi GrokReader Controller Service stackTrace

Tags: apache-nifi, grok

Seems the GrokReader service disregards the GrokPattern and terminates any line after the "Caused by" line in any flowfile that has a stackTrace.

My grokPattern %{EBANK_LOGLEVEL} specifies a Regex expression 
`^([A-a]lert|ALERT|[T|t]race|TRACE|[D|d]ebug|DEBUG|[N|n]otice|NOTICE|[I|i]nfo|INFO|[W|w]arn?(?:ing)?|WARN?(?:ING)?|[E|e]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[C|c]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[F|f]atal|FATAL|[S|s]evere|SEVERE|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?).-\s\w+=\{`

which is supposed to append any lines that do not match the expression to previous messages.

The challenge is that the service ignores the pattern and disregards any other message after the "Caused by" line, instead of appending it to the previous message, until it sees my pattern again and starts a new message.

Is it possible to disable the Stacktrace option on the grokReader?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but have you seen the example in the additional details documentation of the GrokReader? It shows how to capture stacktraces from NiFi's app log https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.9.1/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Thanks @BryanBende yes i did. the only difference is that in the example the stacktrace class continues in the same line as the "caused by" where as my own stacktrace class continues  on the next line after the "caused by". That is the only difference i can see. I was hoping i could disable the stacktrace capturing and have the grokreader treat everything as multiline - appending each line to the previous until it encounters the grok pattern again